# Two measures on a measurable space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to find an example of two finite measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on a measure space $(X,S)$ with $\mu(X)=\nu(X)$ such that  {$A\in S: \mu(A)=\nu(A)$} is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$, choose $\mu$ uniform on $\{a,b\}$ and $\nu$ uniform on $\{c,d\}$. Then $\mu(A)=\nu(A)$ for $A=\{a,c\}$ and $A=\{a,d\}$ but not for $A=\{a\}$. The class $\{A\subseteq X\mid\mu(A)=\nu(A)\}$ is not a sigma-algebra since it is not stable by intersection.

This example can be adapted to every measurable space $(X,S)$ such that $S$ contains four disjoint nonempty subsets of $X$.

Comment: @did This is impressive. Thanks!